# Looking for compatible RAM

Tags: memory, motherboard

Here's what I have currently, and I'm looking to upgrade the RAM to 4Gb. Trouble is I have no idea what to buy!
Main Circuit Board 
Board: ASUSTeK Computer INC. P5KPL-AM 
Serial Number: MT7088K00628521
Bus Clock: 200 megahertz
BIOS: American Megatrends Inc. 0309 05/20/2008 
Memory Modules 
2040 Megabytes Usable Installed Memory
Slot 'DIMM A1' has 1024 MB
Slot 'DIMM B1' has 1024 MB

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the [memory compatibility list](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/socket775/P5KPL-AM/P5KPL-AM_QVL.zip) provided by ASUS for this motherboard.

There are 4 RAM-sticks with 2GB size which would suit your needs.

Comment: Good answer.   I would, however, also point out that this machine is from 2008, and the US$50 it will cost to upgrade the RAM is a waste of money relative to a newer machine  (This motherboard takes a Core 2 CPU, has no HDMI output), and probably uses twice as much power as a new system.

Comment: True, hoewever this machine could still be fast enough for basic office work, which might be all that OP needs. And more RAM certainly helps with this as well. Maybe taking a look at used modules could be recommended as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a set of 2 pieces RAM with following parameters:

- 2GB each (4GB kit is often sold)
- DDR2 (one where the connector is divided almost in the middle)
- dual channel (when sold or used in pairs as in a kit)
- 1066MHz (can be writen PC2-8500)

Your operating system for optimal usage of availiable memory range would need to be configured with PAE, so not just 3GB would be used, but all 4. Not a dealbreaker if not configured anyway.